# ¿Como crear un elemento html con javaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

Quiero crear una tabla dinámica a lo cual ingreso algunos valores, pero al momento de crear las filas en la tabla el botón no me genera nada.

```js
var div = document.getElementById("divTabla");

function crearTabla() {
  var nombre = document.getElementById("nombre").value,
    edad = document.getElementById("edad").value,
    sexo = document.getElementById("sexo".value);

  var columna = document.createElement("tr"),
    celdaNombre = document.createElement("td"),
    celdaEdad = document.createElement("td"),
    celdaSexo = document.createElement("td"),
    celda = document.createElement("td");

  celdaNombre.innerHTML = nombre;
  celdaEdad.innerHTML = edad;
  celdaSexo.innerHTML = sexo;
  celda.innerHTML = "Temporal";

  columna.appendChild(celdaNombre);
  columna.appendChild(celdaEdad);
  columna.appendChild(celdaSexo);
  columna.appendChild(celda);


  tabla = document.getElementById("tabla").appendChild(columna);

}
```

```html
<div>
  <form>
    <input type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre" placeholder="Ingrese nombre">
    <input type="text" name="edad" id="edad" placeholder="ingrese Edad">
    <select name="sexo" id="sexo">
        <option value="Hombre">Hombre</option>
        <option value="Mujer">Mujer</option>
    </select>
    <button onclick="crearTabla()">Agregar</button>
  </form>
  <br><br>
</div>
<div id="divTabla" class="egt">
  <table id="tabla">
    <tr>
      <th>Nombre</th>
      <th>Edad</th>
      <th>Sexo</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>

    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Parece ir bien, se añaden las celdas. ¿Cómo es que no funciona?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El error es que tienes el `<button onclick="crearTabla()">Agregar</button>` dentro de un `form` este se comporta como si fueras a enviar datos por `URL` propongo que saques el `button` del `form` y funcionara perfectamente.

```
<form>
      <input type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre" placeholder="Ingrese nombre">
      <input type="text" name="edad" id="edad" placeholder="ingrese Edad">
      <select name="sexo" id="sexo">
         <option value="Hombre">Hombre</option>
         <option value="Mujer">Mujer</option>
      </select>
</form>
<button onclick="crearTabla()">Agregar</button>
```

Otra solucion seria agregarle al tag `<button>` el tipo es decir, `<button type="button">` e incluirlo dentro del `form` tal como lo tienes.

```
<form>
      <input type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre" placeholder="Ingrese nombre">
      <input type="text" name="edad" id="edad" placeholder="ingrese Edad">
      <select name="sexo" id="sexo">
          <option value="Hombre">Hombre</option>
          <option value="Mujer">Mujer</option>
       </select>
       <button type="button" onclick="crearTabla()">Agregar</button>
</form>
```

Comment: @RichardYordy Si te funciono o no?

Comment: si @Pablo ya funciono.. de hecho con solo sacar el button funciono todo correctamente. muchas gracias..

Comment: @RichardYordy sabes que...Funciona correctamente estando dentro del form pero agregandole a la etiqueta <button> el tipo, es decir <button type="button">, Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Tal vez sea porque tienes un error en la línea 5 del código que mostrastes aquí

```
sexo = document.getElementById("sexo".value);
```

Debe ser:

```
sexo = document.getElementById("sexo").value;
```

Te faltaba el paréntesis. Por lo demás creo que todo está bien. Aunque debo resaltar que estas creando 4 celdas y en las cabeceras tienes 3 nada más. No es un error pero por si no lo habías notado

Comment: Ya lo verifique pero sigue igual.. ese error solo evita que que aparesca el sexo, lo de las celdas si lo note pero pero en realidad no afecta solo afecta en el diseño de la tabla que estoy creando.

Answer (score 0):

Con Jquery

```
/* Note that the whole content variable is just a string */
/*El limite del contador del for es 3 pero ahi va el que tu quieras segun los datos que tengas*/
var content = "<table>"
for(i=0; i<3; i++){
    content += '<tr><td>' + 'Name ' +  '</td><td>' + 'Edad' + '</td><td>' + 'Sexo' '</td></tr>';
}
content += "</table>";

$('#here_table').append(content);
```